# I can not access my product ids and my product categories, here is my controller, I have the following error message:

Tags: .net, api, controller, frameworks, entity

AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: ApiBurgerNew.Controllers.BurgerController.GetBurgerByCat (ApiBurgerNew) ApiBurgerNew.Controllers.BurgerController.GetBurgerById (ApiBurgerNew)

My controller :

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api")]
    public class BurgerController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly BurgerContext _context;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public BurgerController(BurgerContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _context = context;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        
        [HttpGet]        
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBurger()
        {
            var burger = await _context.Burger.ToListAsync();
            return Ok(burger);
        }
        
        //By category
        [HttpGet("{cat}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBurgerByCat(string cat)
        {
            var requete =                
                from b in _context.Burger                    
                join c in _context.Category                
                on b.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId                
                select new { b.BurgerId, b.Name, b.Description, b.Price, c.Category_Name };
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cat))
                requete = requete.Where(p => p.Category_Name.Contains(cat));
            return Ok(requete);

        }
        
        //By Id
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBurgerById(int id)
        {
            var burger = await _context.Burger.FindAsync(id);
            if (burger == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(burger);
        }
    }





I tried to modify my routes but without success
```

Comment: For the future, please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

GetBurgerByCat and GetBurgerById both use the same route. change it like this ( although this API route naming is not a good practice, it's better to use query ):

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api")]
    public class BurgerController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly BurgerContext _context;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public BurgerController(BurgerContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _context = context;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        
        [HttpGet]        
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBurger()
        {
            var burger = await _context.Burger.ToListAsync();
            return Ok(burger);
        }
        
        //By category
        [HttpGet("bycat/{cat}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBurgerByCat(string cat)
        {
            var requete =                
                from b in _context.Burger                    
                join c in _context.Category                
                on b.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId                
                select new { b.BurgerId, b.Name, b.Description, b.Price, c.Category_Name };
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cat))
                requete = requete.Where(p => p.Category_Name.Contains(cat));
            return Ok(requete);

        }
        
        //By Id
        [HttpGet("byuser/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetBurgerById(int id)
        {
            var burger = await _context.Burger.FindAsync(id);
            if (burger == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(burger);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @pacmy there is no screenshot link in your comment